# Converting a macro parameter and turning it into a stringstream

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros, stringstream

I have a parameter in my `LOG()` macro called `msg`.  I am using this macro to perform logging.

Currently this is what `LOG()` looks like:

```
#define LOG(level, msg, logger, ...) { \
    Log(level, msg, logger, __VA_ARGS__) \
}
```

What I would like to do is accept the `<<` operator to append additional information to the `msg`, something like this:

```
int b = 1000;
std::string a = "I love coding";
LOG(WARN, "Hello World! A: " << a << b, "Logger1", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);
```

My `Log()` function (not the macro) is overloaded:

```
Log(Level level, const std::string& msg, const std::string& logger)

Log(Level level, const std::string& msg, const std::string& logger, char* fileName, const char* functionName, int lineNumber)
```

I have tried:

```
#define LOG(level, msg, logger, ...) { \
    std::stringstream temp(msg);  \
    std::string message = temp.str(); \
    atk::core::Logger::Log(level, message, logger, __VA_ARGS__) \
}
```

But I receive many errors in my test application.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

I'd like to be able to do this inside of the macro, and not have to do something like this instead:

```
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << "Text" << std::endl;
std::string s = buffer.str();
LOG(WARN, s, "Logger1", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);
```

Comment: Avoid macros (that look like functions). Prefer `const` or `constexpr` to `#define`.

Comment: `std::stringstream temp; temp << msg;` should do the trick.

Comment: Put your comment as an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: you have to make sure that 'msg' is quoted, otherwise it will become `#msg`

Comment: This is the kind of situation you really shouldn't be using a macro for. I would suggest creating a `Logger` class that supports `operator<<`, then you can do things like this: `Logger(WARN, "Logger1", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__) << "Hello World! A: " << a << b;` Easily implemented using a `std::ostringstream` associated with a custom `std::basic_stringbuf` that writes to your log when flushed.